Prevent same name overwrite with robocopy
I need to prevent robocopy from overwriting files in the destination folder if they already exist, I don't see a flag to do that in the manual.

How do I prevent robocopy from overwriting files in the destination folder
You need to combine several switches:
/XC /XN /XO

/XC Exclude Changed files.
/XN Exclude Newer files.
/XO Exclude Older - if destination file already exists and is the same date or newer than the source, don’t overwrite it.

When changed, older, and newer classes are excluded, robocopy will exclude files that exist in the destination directory.

Further Reading

An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com
Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD | SS64.com
robocopy | SS64.com - Robust File and Folder Copy.


It's crazy it's not a simple switch(or made as a default) things can easily get accidentally overwritten.

@maxical At least it's not the triple-negatives that appear in the registry settings
